MinT hierarchical reconciliation with nonnegative constraints? hts vs fable?
Q: How can I perform hierarchical reconciliation:

of a variety of base forecast models with the MinT algo (ideally),
with nonnegative reconciled forecast outputs (necessarily),
which are distributed (necessarily, either closed form or simulated),
within the R tidyverts/fable framework (ideally)?

Here are a couple options I tried. Unfortunately, both fall short of my needs:

fabletools::min_trace(method='mint_shrink'): I love that this has the Unfortunately, this does not have a non-negativity parameter. So my forecasts, even if guaranteed positive because of a log-transformation, reconciled with negative values. This is such a bummer, because it can even produce a distribution of reconciled forecasts (empirical) through bootstrap sampling base forecast model residuals as base forecast model forecast errors, and then reconciling each of those bootstrap simulated forecasts.
hts::forecast.gts(fmethod='arima', weights='mint', nonnegative=TRUE): This function is supposed to be superseded by the previous, but it does have some functionality that doesn't exist in fabletools::min_trace(), namely, a nonnegative=TRUE option. Unfortunately, the only fmethod options are 'ets', 'arima', and 'rw'. This is quite limiting for my case. I need to play with a variety of base forecast models---even things as simple as  forcing a differencing parameter d=1 in the arima model, which I can do in fable via ARIMA(y~pdq(d=1)) but cannot do here in hts.

Maybe I'm something, a parameter, a function, a package, understanding? I hope I am. If so, please let me know. Otherwise,
Q: what would you suggest as an approach?
Right now, I think the best option for me is the following:

produce base forecasts (non-negative outputs)
reconcile base forecasts via fabletools::min_trace() (possible negative outputs)
for the reconciled forecasts at the lowest level of the hierarchy, set all negatives to zeros
propagate the difference up to the next level of the hierarchy, repeating until I've reached the top level
repeat all this via the bootstrapping procedure described in Reconciled Distributional Forecasts.

But maybe there's a better approach?

Currently, I think what you have proposed is the best approach. In step 4, I assume you mean add up the bottom level reconciled forecasts (after setting negatives to zero) to obtain higher level forecasts.
We are doing a major rewrite of reconciliation in fable to enable it to handle a lot more features. Until that is ready, we have paused porting some of the functionality that is only available in hts.
I think you can also do what you are proposing in a non-tidyverse way with the FoReco package.

Thanks Rob. Someone else pointed me to the bayesRecon, which effectively implements a probabilistic MinT. I'll have a look at both.
